# GridBagLayout doesn't take up all the available space

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

When initialising a panel and setting it to GridBagLayout, the two encapsulated panels do not expand to fill all the available area. Like so:

[image: As you can see it is a lot smaller compared to the available space]

Code:

```
    containerPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    add(containerPanel);

    contentPanel = new JPanel();

    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;

    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;

    containerPanel.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));

    containerPanel.add(contentPanel, constraints);

    sidebarPanel = new JPanel();

    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;

    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 0;

    constraints.weightx = 0.33;
    constraints.weighty = 2;

    sidebarPanel.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));

    containerPanel.add(sidebarPanel, constraints);
```

Comment: So, based on my little bit of testing, both panels fill the vertical space, which raises the question of, what is the layout manager been used by the container that `containerPanel` is added to?

Comment: @MadProgrammer FlowLayout, ive tried other layouts however the same thing happens

Comment: Use a `BorderLayout`, the problem is, none of the panes actually have a physical (preferredSize), so they are been laid out at `0x0` (plus the requirements of the border)

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.